# How to check producer's id, client id in Kafka using java?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I want to check id and client id of producer in kafka. I know we can't access them in the consumer, so where can I find the ids? Can I get them before sending the message or is it somewhere there in the logs?

Answer (score 0):

you can find logs like

```
[Producer clientId=producer-1]
```

and

```
[Consumer clientId=test-client-id, groupId=test-id2]
```

if you want to get client id using java,read the API AdminClient

```
 Map<String, ConsumerGroupDescription> allGroupDetails = client.describeConsumerGroups(allGroups).all().get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

ConsumerGroupDescription -> Collection -> clientId